# Setting VirtualBox host system resolution to max screen size creates vertical & horizontal scrollbars

Tags: windows-10, window

I'm on a Windows 10 PC with 1680 x 1050 monitor resolution.

I've used the following command to set my VirtualBox guest system display size to 1680x1050

```
VBoxManage setextradata "OS" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1680x1050
```

Setting the VirtualBox guest system resolution to max screen size creates vertical & horizontal scrollbars in the VirtualBox window.

From [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/signindialogtitlebars#:%7E:text=The%20title%20bar%20has%20a,will%20be%20clamped%20to%2050.), I gather the Title, File & Status bar are 25 pixels tall, so I edit my command to be:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "OS" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1605x1050
```

However, the guest system has gone back to 1024 x 728.

Is it possible to set a custom display size, or are they predefined?

How do I set the guest system's screen to be as large as possible without the scrollbars?

I'm running Windows 10.

Help appreciated.

Comment: In the Guest machine, you should be able to set the guest view to fit the Virtual Box overall window. Then it will fit without scroll bars  You cannot set it bigger that this and still have no scroll bats.

Comment: Ensuring that Guest Additions are installed, set "View > Auto-resize guest display". You may now resize the display to fill the screen. You also need to have enough video memory in "Settings > Display", like 128 MB.